# Issue with links (like a href) in Zend

Tags: zend-framework, exception, url, dispatcher

I've got a problem with Zend Framework, when calling an action.

This action is called "uploadvideo" inside a controller called "UploadInterfaceController".
Therefor the view is called "uploadvideo.phtml".

Now all this is wrapped in a module called "Upload".

The problem is, that I cannot call a link inside the uploadvideo.phtml.
I tried following code:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('action'=>'uploadvideo','controller'=>'Uploadinterface','module'=>'upload',)); ?> "
```

and it produces me a nice clean URL (webroot/public/upload/UploadInterface/videoupload).

.

**But**

A dispatcher-error occurs, which I can't explain:

```
Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception: Invalid controller class ("Upload_UploadinterfaceControll") [...]
```

I don't get it, where ZF is getting the "Upload_" prefix.
I tried renaming the Controllers (and the representing entries in .zfproject.xml) but it stays the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using modules, your controllers need to have the module name as a prefix (except for the default module).

So your upload module controllers class names need to start with "Upload_".

Answer (score 1):

The error states "Invalid Controller Class" are you sure you are extending Zend_Controller_Action?

Comment: Yeah, I created the controller via zend tool.

Something that bothers me is, that zend tool isn't considering the module-name. It could easily put the MODULENAME_ prefix onto the classname.

Comment: Actually it does create the prefix.. must have deleted it earlier